# What prevents a random developer from using my client id to get user access tokens?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

When using FB's javascript SDK, it only requires your client app id. What is stopping someone from finding out your client app id and using that to log in users and getting access tokens to information it thinks it is giving your app?

I realize there are many more security steps that can be taken here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security#proof

But the default behavior looks like anyone can pretend to be your app and get user info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth2 clients (applications) have a registered set of redirect URIs that point to their installations. If an attacker initiates authentication using some other client's ID, he must specify a valid redirect URI, the browser will be redirected to after the auth process. So the resulting token will not be delivered to the attacker, but the client's application.

This kind of attack is called "client impersonation" and the [OAuth2 RFC discusses it](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.2). It's also discussed in [OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252#section-8.6).

Comment: Unfortunately the Redirect URI that will contain the Authorization Code (and the state if provided) can be MITM and the Code can be extracted from there. From what I am aware, there isn't a way to be sure that a real client is making the requests to your API.

Comment: I think you cannot use a man-in-the-middle attack if the connection is secured. And Facebook uses HTTPS for their services.

Answer (score 1):

The JS SDK will only work on your domain, you need to add it in the App settings. So there is no security issue, just try it.

Also, only users themselves can log in with their account, you cannot just log in any user just because you have the App ID.